# parse value from a php jsonstring in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting following json from php

```
{"status":{"message":"success","undeleted":[],"code":200}}


{"status":{"message":"success","undeleted":[{"id":7844118,"error":"This Document already Published"}],"code":200}}
```

I just want to check 'undeleted' is empty or not in jquery.If not empty,I need to take every ids and its error message from 'undeleted'.I am not getting an idea how to do this .I will get only one at a time.

Thinking about something like this

```
var result = jQuery.parseJSON(data);

          $.each(result.data, function(index, value) {
});
```

I have done something like this but not getting desired answer

```
var result = jQuery.parseJSON(data);

$.each(result.status, function(index, value) {
    alert(value);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here is how to do it:**

http://jsfiddle.net/2zLby4r8/3/

```
var result = jQuery.parseJSON('{"status":{"message":"success","undeleted":[{"id":7844118,"error":"This Document already Published"},{"id":999999,"error":"New Errr"}],"code":200}}');

if (result.status.undeleted.length > 0) {

    $.each(result.status.undeleted, function(index, value) {
         alert("ID: " + value.id);
         alert("Error: " + value.error);
    });

} else {

    alert("blank"); 

}
```

Comment: how can I get the ids & error ? something like posible alert(result.status.undeleted[0]['id']);

Comment: if I have a more than one id, can I use loop ?